# Finding if a Set containing a given object or not

Tags: java, collections

A Set contains only one object of entity Community and i am using two objects of same value and one of the objects is stored in that Set

```
Set<Community> communties = template.get(User.class, "1").getCommunities();
Community com = template.get(Community.class, 1);

for(Community community : communties)
        System.out.println(community.equals(com));

System.out.println(communties.contains(com));
```

First Statement prints `true` but Second Statement prints `false`. Why?

Comment: Have you overridden equals() but not hashCode() in your Community class?

Comment: yes! overriden only `equals()` and not `hashCode()`

Comment: I have posted the solution as an answer, please kindly accept it if you feel it's OK so that question registers as solved. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must override hashCode() as well as equals(), otherwise, the Set won't find the correct bucket for the object and will not even arrive to the equals() comparison.

You can use Eclipse "Source" menu to generate pretty decent equals() and hashCode() methods.

Comment: Paste your equals() and hashCode() methods, please.

Comment: My `Community.java` contains other two Set<Entity> and if i removed from `equals()` and `hashCode()`.. it is working!

Comment: it means other two entities also should override `equals()` and `hashCode()` ??

Comment: Is it working right already? With hashCode() and equals()? Anyway, here you have an in-depth explanation of hashCode() and equals() implementation (worth reading it to clarify concepts): http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/equalhash.html